# jQuery slideToggle() callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, slidetoggle

Here is the jQuery slideToggle function:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // how can I access $('.class') that was clicked on
        // $(this) returns the $(this).parent().next() which is the element
        // that is currently being toggled/slided
    });
});
```

In the callback function I need to access current .class element (the one being clicked on). How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a reference to the element outside of the callback, you can then use this inside the callback function.

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
         //use $el here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't think of such easy solution.